# How can I add an 'ended' function to .animate()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the following jQuery statement, I'm attempting to enable the pointer events when the button animation completes, but it is unclear to me how to implement an `ended` or `complete` function. Any recommendations?

```
$('#certButton').delay(5500).animate({ 'opacity': [ 1, "linear" ]}, 500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/animate/), this can be added as the 4th parameter of the `animate()` function, like that:

```
$('#certButton').delay(5500).animate(
    { 'opacity': 1 },
    500, 
    "linear",   
    function() {

    }
);
```

**Update:**

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gchameleon/dxx3x77w/). 
I am also unsure why this line

```
{ 'opacity': [ 1, "linear" ]}
```

works, but I think the syntax conforming with the documentation I used above looks cleaner, and functions the same (see the JSFiddle).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I have reworked it off your answers to the below code.

```
$('#certButton').delay(500).animate({ 'opacity': [ 1, "linear" ]}, {
    duration:500,
    complete: function() {
        document.getElementById("certButton").style.pointerEvents = "visible"; 
    }
});
```

Comment: since you are new, consider upvoting / marking the answer that helped you as the right answer! it will help other people that have the same problem as you